# Spring Data Elasticsearch Nested query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, jhipster

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch support via jHipster, and am trying to learn a bit more about using search as it relates to extending some new relationships in my database.

I've got a new nested relationship with it's own index:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friends")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "friend")
public class Friend {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @Field(type=FieldType.Nested, index=FieldIndex.analyzed, store=true)
    private User friend1;

    @OneToOne
    @Field(type=FieldType.Nested, index=FieldIndex.analyzed, store=true)
    private User friend2;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getFriend1() {
        return friend1;
    }

    public void setFriend1(User friend1) {
        this.friend1 = friend1;
    }

    public User getFriend2() {
        return friend2;
    }

    public void setFriend2(User friend2) {
        this.friend2 = friend2;
    }

}
```

I want to filter the results to a specific user "friend1.id", and than search for matching details on the nested document?

```
     StreamSupport
        .stream(friendSearchRepository.search(
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()               
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("friend1.id",SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserId()))
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("friend2.login",query))).spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This doesn't seem to return any results though?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how to search this, an Elasticsearch query can be constructed using [QueryBuilders](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.7.3/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.html). For example, `querySearchQuery` can be combined with other types of queries using a `boolQuery`:

`userSearchRepository.search(
    QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(queryStringQuery(query))
    .must(termsQuery("firstName", "John")))`

This will search for `User`s where the query matches and `firstName` is `John`.

Comment: So looking at [queryStringQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), which includes a lot of terms but few examples, perhaps: [has child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html), but don't I have to change my index somehow?